# Migrating Struts 2.3 to 2.5

Tags: java, struts2, migration, tiles, struts2-tiles-plugin

I was facing some issues while Struts migrating,
I was using Tiles in my application. Below was the error:

```
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/struts2/tiles/StrutsTilesListener: Unsupportedd major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2822)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadClassAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:144)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:56)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:353)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:885)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:317)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5081)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

This was the filter using in `web.xml`:

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of class `org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener` is 51.0 which corresponds to Java SE 7.

You can use [Java : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0/) solution to update your java installation.